# How can we use INSTANA to monitor & manage Apache Kafka and Zookeeper cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apm, instana

I have set up a Kafka & Zookeeper cluster in Production. I need to set up INSTANA APM Tool to monitor and manage the Production Kafka & Zookeeper Cluster. Did anyone  has ever used INSTANA to monitor Kafka . Kindly share your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: I work for Instana.

There is not much to setup. Instana provides out-of-the-box support for Kafka and Zookeeper nodes. So all you need to do is to install the Instana agent on the server(s) you want to monitor. It will automatically detect your Kafka and Zookeeper installations and start reporting metrics for them to your tenant unit. If you don't have a tenant unit yet, you can register for a free trial at https://www.instana.com/trial/ or contact Sales.

If you need additional help, I suggest to open a ticket at https://instana.zendesk.com to get dedicated support.